# Jquery Ui Autocomplete duplicate results for tags

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete, json

Hi i want to work with autocomplete but the results are duplicated . Sorry for my poor English. First of all My mysql table named "**firma**"

```
Example:
    id | etiket 
    1  | tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4,tag5,Merkez
    2  | tag1,tag2,tag6,Merkez
    3  | tag1,tag3,tag4,tag10,Merkez
    ...............................
```

Please Attention: Merkez's are  **same tags** seperate with commas.

search.php file

```
 $term=$_GET['term'];

  $req = "SELECT etiket FROM firma WHERE etiket LIKE '%".$term."%'"; 

     $query = mysql_query($req);
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
     {

        $degisken_array = explode(',',$row['etiket']);
        foreach($degisken_array as $deger)
     {
         $deger = trim($deger);
          $results[] = array('label' => $deger);
     }
        }
     echo json_encode($results);
```

Html part of file..

```
<div class="ui-widget">
  <div class="cerceve">
 <input style="width:550px" id="birds" type="text" <?php if(isset($_GET['kelime'])) { 
  if($_GET["kelime"]!='') { echo "class='arasecili'"; } } ?> name="kelime"  placeholder="Örn: > Firma, kurum, işletme adı.. "  >

 </div>
  </div>
```

Javascript part..

```
   <script>
    $(function() {
        var cache = {};
        $( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
            minLength: 2,
            source: function( request, response ) {
                var term = request.term;
                if ( term in cache ) {
                    response( cache[ term ] );
                    return;
                }

                $.getJSON( "search.php", request, function( data, status, xhr ) {
                    cache[ term ] = data;
                    response( data );
                });
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

And output is as this as you can see in image when i type "Merkez" to the search box , there are 3 results for Merkez, how can i get only once for every tag

You can see results and problem here.

http://i.hizliresim.com/wOgRLA.png

Answer (score 0):

You can use the array_unique() function on your $results array. This should remove doubles.
http://de3.php.net/manual/de/function.array-unique.php

Answer (score 0):

little bit old question but I hope will help to someone like me can't find the answers.
I make it works like this:
to remove duplicates from an array and put in to the .autocomplete() you will need 2 steps

```
$arr = ['0','0','1','2',...
$arrUnique = array_values(array_unique($arr));
```

because only array_unique with json_encode will output

```
{"0":"0","1":"1","2":"2",...
```

but with the array_values will output

```
['0','1','2',...
```